# Cannot resolve Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure-Web-Site setup to deploy via git, however when I do, I'm getting a compiler error stating:

> D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

This is on a seperate project than my MVC project that does have Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient as a reference and within the properties I do have it set to CopyLocal

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when you have "Copy Local" property set to "true" you still need to be sure that when you deployed your application to Windows Azure, all the files are deployed. I believe the key is that when you run "git commit" be sure the list all the files which will be pushed.

For example when I ran **git commit -m "initial commit"** I can verify below that Windows Azure Storage related references are included as below:

[image]

After that when you will call **git push azure master** these additional references will sure to be deployed.

All my steps during my Git test are documented in my blog [Using Git to deploy an ASP.NET website shows Windows Azure Blob Storage list at Windows Azure Websites](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2012/06/19/using-git-to-deploy-an-asp-net-website-shows-windows-azure-blob-storage-list-at-windows-azure-websites.aspx).

Comment: I assume you are checking in all dependencies rather than allowing nuget to restore them?  This is where my git deploy fails http://stackoverflow.com/q/16709995/137474