# Azure websites Deploy from Source Control fails on nuget dependency

Tags: azure, nuget, bitbucket, msdeploy

Asp.Net v4 Webforms App has a dependency on Windows.Azure.Storage.  This all works fine if i use WebDeploy to deploy it to Azure Websites.

Now i want to use a branch in my bitbucket repo to have it auto deploy from source control.

I set up the branch, linked azure to it, and then triggered a deploy.

But it fails, and this is in the Azure log...

> D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\kdb\VirtualDirectory0\site\repository\Pfv.Kdb.UI\Kdb.UI.csproj]

Nuget has package restore enabled, and i checked nuget.targets to ensure that DownloadNugetExe condition is set to true.

Why is it failing to pull in the nuget dependencies?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but with CrystalReports as the assemblies that can't be found.

Comment: This would suggest that checking them in works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106191/cannot-resolve-microsoft-windowsazure-storageclient?rq=1. But the question remains, why does nuget package restore fail on azure?

Answer (score -1):

I have just tried out creating a MVC4 app in VS2012 referencing Windows.Azure.Storage nuget package and succesfuuly pushed it from local git to windows azure without any issues.

I did not hit this issue. I have enabled nuget package restore and also included a .gitignore in to my git repo not to push binary and package files.

I also saw this with pushing the repo to WAWS.

remote:   Successfully installed 'WindowsAzure.Storage 2.0.5.1'.